# how can i unshuffle function in python by the pattern of list?

Tags: python, function

o is the standard of pattern to un_shuffle

```
o = [2,1,3,0]
a = 'abcd'

def un_suffle(s,o):
   s = 'bcda'
   return ''.join([s[i] for i in o])
print(un_suffle(s,o))
```

my output is:

```
dcab # i want to make it abcd in output
```

Comment: this will give you an error 'n' is not defined in the print function.

Comment: you want it to be 'abcd', but variable a is already 'abcd', so what is your point?

Comment: my point wont to make the unshuffle from bcda to become abcd base on the list of o

Comment: BTW: you should define `s = 'bcda'` outside function to send it as argument.

Comment: to unshufle `s` to `a` you need `o = [3,0,1,2]` and to shuffle `a` to `c` you would need `o = [1,2,3,0]`. In both situations you have wrong values in your `o` BTW: for `s = 'bcda'` you can do `s[-1:] + s[:-1]` to get `a` because it needs only to move last element to first place.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that 's' is not a shuffled version of 'a' based on the order you express in 'o'.

The second problem is that if you are un-shuffling, you should iterate through the list 'o' backwards from the order you shuffled it in.

Try to make a shuffle function first, then make an un-shuffle function. You're on the right track.